# Firebase authentication fail

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the steps of Firebase to create new users and I get an error, this is my method and is called by one onClickListener, what's wrong?

```
private void newUser(){

    String finalEmail, finalPassword, repassw;
    finalEmail = email.getText().toString();
    finalPassword = password.getText().toString();
    repassw = repassword.getText().toString();

    if (finalPassword.equals(repassw)){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(finalEmail, finalPassword).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Sucessfull!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Not the same password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `"Error!"` with `task.getException().getMessage()` and please tell us what you get\

Comment: Dam, i was using 123 as password and should be at least 6 characters, thank you so much!!

Comment: no problem, good luck!